# How to find commit hash from within a running docker image

Tags: git, image, docker, docker-swarm

I currently build my images and tag them with the commit hash. I then pull this image and run it (either via the commit hash or the `latest` tag). How can I find out the commit hash from a running container ?

All I currently know is the container `hostname`. So if the container is running I can get the digest:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Image}}' hostname
```

Then from the digest I can search on Dockerhub to find the tag linked to the digest (not sure how to do it) and then the tag has the commit hash linked to it.

Unfortunately, if the container is not still active I get the error:

```
Error: No such object: hostname
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: A bit confused, you said "I build the images and tag them with commit hash and pull the image either via `commit hash` or `latest` tag". My question is can we pull the images with `latest` tag which are tagged with `commit hash`? AFAIK, we can't pull image with `latest` tag which are pushed with `commit hash`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you can tag the same image multiple times (i.e latest **and** commit hash)

Comment: Ohk, so you pushed 2 different images. One with `latest` tag and another with `commit hash` ? and then pulled the image with `latest` tag, correct?

Comment: No. I pushed the same image with two tags.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the option that you can try is to set `commit hash` in the environment variable, so you will able to get the `ENV` from the image as well.

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD) -t my_image:$(git rev-parse HEAD) .
```

and the Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ENV GIT_COMMIT=$GIT_COMMIT
```

Now you can get `GIT_COMMIT` from env

```
echo "${GIT_COMMIT}"
```

Comment: I think this should be `docker build --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD) -t my_image:$(git rev-parse HEAD) <path to Dockerfile>`

Comment: @f01 yes true `-t` was missing

Comment: It is not fair that the built container image does not automatically save commit hash in its info.

Comment: If you use github actions, try `GIT_COMMIT=${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.id }}`

Comment: yes and in Gitlab `GIT_COMMIT=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}`

Comment: How to use it in windows command line?